# 80's movie involving replacing actors with CGI

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was a movie I saw a few times on British TV during the 80's, but I don't think it was much older than that. English language, almost certainly American-produced. I think it was an action movie, driven by a multiple murder plot.

The main scene I remember (I really want to say it was the opening scene, but I'm not 100% certain of that) had a couple running along the beach being filmed for a commercial, and the production crew were upset that when they jumped they weren't twisting as far as the computer said they should.

I think there was also an early scene where an actress fell from a hotel window, which was later discovered to be murder, though I might well be conflating another movie there.

I know this isn't a lot of detail, but it's been bugging me recently and I'd really like to know what it was. Thanks.

Comment: This question would be improved if you went through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Valorum I've added a little more detail, but unfortunately, there's really very little I remember.

Comment: Just to clarify, the science fiction aspect is how perfectly the people are replaced by CGI? That would be pretty impressive in the 80s.

Comment: @Jenayah It looks like it's the same answer, but there's no way I'd have recognised it from that question.

Comment: Oh sure, but [per policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/98028) we close story-id as dupes when both have the same accepted answer. On story-id it doesn't mean authors should have recognized the work from the target question; the closure is there to tell future readers "if you're searching for this work, you'll find more info there".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to guess *[Looker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looker)* (1981)

[image: Movie poster for *Looker*]

> Dr. Larry Roberts (Finney), a Beverly Hills plastic surgeon, is puzzled when four beautiful models working in television commercials request cosmetic surgery to make changes so minor as to be imperceptible to the naked eye. When these models later start dying under mysterious circumstances, he discovers they are all linked to the same advertisement research firm.
>
> The Digital Matrix research firm rates advertising models using a scoring system to measure the combined visual impact of various physical attributes in television commercials. In an experiment to increase their scores, some models are sent to Dr. Roberts to get cosmetic surgery to maximize their visual impact. Though the models are physically perfect after the surgery, they still are not as effective as desired, so the research firm decides to use a different approach. Each model is offered a contract to have her body scanned digitally to create 3D computer-generated models, then the 3D models are animated for use in commercials. The contracts seem to be incredibly lucrative for the models; once their bodies are represented digitally, they get a paycheck for life, never having to work again, since their digital models are used for all their future work in commercials.
>
> However, when these same models start dying under mysterious circumstances, Roberts becomes suspicious and decides to investigate Digital Matrix. He has a strong interest in investigating the deaths: he is considered a prime suspect by the police (from evidence planted at the scene of one of the murders) and his most recent patient, (with whom he is in a relationship) Cindy (Susan Dey). Cindy is the last of the models to be digitally scanned.
>
> During his investigation, Roberts discovers some advanced technology that the Digital Matrix corporation is using to hypnotize consumers into buying the products they advertise. He also discovers the Light Ocular-Oriented Kinetic Emotive Responses (L.O.O.K.E.R.) gun, a light pulse device that gives the illusion of invisibility by instantly mesmerizing its victims into losing all sense of time.

Found by searching for `film murder "actors replaced * computers"`, which took me to the Wikipedia entry for [Virtual actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_actor), which mentions *Looker*.

[This review](https://birthmoviesdeath.com/2016/08/03/everybodys-into-weirdness-looker-1981) mentions the falling death:

> .... Stalked by a shadowy figure hiding behind her curtains, Lisa (Terri Welles) falls to her death from the balcony of a glass-laden apartment after being inexplicably frozen by some sort of unseen interval-halting firearm.

### Trailer

Comment: Ninja'd! I agree that this is it. Nice job.

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you so much for this.